# Modal And Input Type FILE ANGULAR

Tags: angular, file, input

i work for a personal project (a social network). Users can create, modify et delete Post and they can comment each post

I work on Angular

I have a post-list component which display posts.
I create a fonction to open a modal to display a Form to create a post

```
    displayForm() {
    const dialogConfig = new MatDialogConfig();
    dialogConfig.disableClose = false;
    dialogConfig.autoFocus = true;
    dialogConfig.width = "600px";
    dialogConfig.maxWidth = "80%";
    this.dialog.open(FormPostComponent, dialogConfig);
}
```

On the Html of FormPostComponent i have an input type File if the user want to upload an image

```
<div>
    <label for="file" class="label-file " id="label">Ou choisir une image</label>
    <input
        #fileinput
        type="file"
        class="input-file"
        id="file"
        formControlName="file"
        (change)="addFile($event)"
    />
</div>
```

The problem is i can't have access to the file, the file seems to be retrieved by another input behind the modal.

I find a solution with set in my modalCompononent : encapsulation : ViewEncapsulation.ShadowDom but i don't think it's the solution because ShadowDom is not supported with all the browsers

```
@Component({
selector: "app-form-post",
templateUrl: "./form-post.component.html",
styleUrls: ["./form-post.component.scss"],
encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.ShadowDom,
```

})

the path of the input change

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It's nested in the target element property.

```
addFile(event: any) {
    const files: File[] = event.target.files;
}
```

This is cleaner. Pass on the input element directly:

```
<input #fileinput
(change)="addFile(this.fileinput)"
...
```

and retrieve it:

```
addFile(input: HTMLInputElement) {
    const files: FileList | null = input.files;
}
```

Comment: I think it may need `event.target.files[0]` to grab the first file available! not sure though